# Self destructing/terminating/stopping webapp

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

I would like to know which possibilities do you know to
make a maven webapp destructing/terminating or to stop itself after it run a specified command.

My plan is to have a maven webapp which receives commands and terminates itself after run a command. In case I need it again, I want to run the maven webapp again and then stopping/terminating periodically.

Maybe it is possible to stop a library ? (Just in case a webapp can't be stopped).

I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably misunderstanding how do web applications work and how is their lifecycle. You need to have a servlet container (usually Tomcat) and then deploy your webapp into this container. The container is then responsible for starting, running, and stopping the webapp. So you need to tell the container to stop the webapp. Or, if you have only one webapp in your container, you can shut down the whole container.

Both things (how to manage webapps in container and how to shut down the container) are container specific, you have to read the documentation. If you use Tomcat, you can send a shutdown command (string) to a particular port - both command and port are specified in `server.xml` file.

**DO NOT** call `System.exit(0)` (as suggested by Lance Java)! Yes, it will work and stop bot the webapp and container, but it won't let the container to perform a proper clean-up, and may lead to problems when trying to start it again.